# JQuery .css() on variable div id

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm just going to build a nice hover menu.

There are various divs to be displayed when the user moves the mouse over the menu.

Here is my HTML Code:

```
<ul class="menue">
  <li><a href="#">Startseite</a></li>
  <li id="1"><a href="#">Menü1</a></li>
  <li id="2"><a href="#">Menü2</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="subMenue" id="2">Test-Menue1</div>
<div class="subMenue" id="2">Test-Menue2</div>
```

And here is the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".menue li").mouseover(function(){
        if($(this).attr('id')){
            $(".subMenue #" + $(this).attr('id')).css("display", "block");
        }
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $(".subMenue #" + $(this).attr('id')).css("display", "none");
    });
});
```

How can I get now is that if I go over the `<li>` with id 1, the `<div>` with the id 1 rises?
With the possibility of mine described above it is not unfortunately.

Comment: You cannot have duplicated `id` values.  `id` must be unique within the document.

Comment: "How can I get now is that if". what??

Comment: You shouldn't have duplicate IDs, nor number-only IDs.

Comment: CSS id should be unique per page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have issues like:

- Duplicate ID being used. Your selector will end up having issues apart from having invalid html.
- Selector incorrect `.subMenue #1` should be `.subMenue#1`.

You can use a custom `data-target` attribute on li's to provide the target's selector (**to avoid any string concatenation for calculating the target's id and flexibility of having any kind of selector with any nesting**) instead of ids and just do `$(".subMenue" +  $(this).data('target'))` to select the respective elements. This is kind of pattern framworks like bootstrap follows.

Try this way:

#### Html

```
<ul class="menue">
  <li><a href="#">Startseite</a></li>
  <li data-target="#1"><a href="#">Menü1</a></li>
  <li data-target="#2"><a href="#">Menü2</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="subMenue" id="1">Test-Menue1</div>
<div class="subMenue" id="2">Test-Menue2</div>
```

#### Script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".menue li").mouseover(function(){
          $(".subMenue" +  $(this).data('target')).css("display", "block");
    }).mouseout(function(){
         $(".subMenue" + $(this).data('target')).css("display", "none");
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H86GA/)**

As a shortcut you can even use a one liner using `.toggle()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".menue li").hover(function(){
          $(".subMenue" +  $(this).data('target')).toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Nice, very nice. But now, I have another Problem. If i leave the `<li>` to click something in the `<div>` the `<div>` close... Have u any idea to fix this?

Comment: @VicoDambeck It depends on the design and your ui are you going to have it as a div outside always as you have given in the example?

Comment: Yes it's a outside div under the horizontal menue.
Here is an demo of my try:
http://jsfiddle.net/aeNhf/

Comment: @VicoDambeck Since your divs are far apart you will have to do this way.. http://jsfiddle.net/gguk9/ mouse out of div will hide it.

Comment: @VicoDambeck to be more precise. hover over the same menu once again will hide it or mouseleave of the div will also hide it.. http://jsfiddle.net/n7meS/

Comment: Sure, but when i mouseenter the Menü1 for example and then i scroll down to content of my page, the div is visible anyway. U now what i mean? 
This is an better example of my problem. http://jsfiddle.net/w264A/

Comment: You dont want it to be visible when out of focus of the div right? like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Ze2ca/

Comment: No if u focus the Menü2 Button and then go right-side out. The div is also visible.

Comment: @VicoDambeck Your divs are absolute so just put them inside respective li's if thats the case..

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<ul class="menue">
  <li><a href="#">Startseite</a></li>
  <li class="menu" data-id="sub1"><a href="#">Menü1</a></li>
  <li class="menu" data-id="sub2"><a href="#">Menü2</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="subMenue" id="sub1">Test-Menue1</div>
<div class="subMenue" id="sub2">Test-Menue2</div>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.menue > li.menu').mouseenter(function(){
    $('#' + $(this).data('id')).css('display', 'block');

}).mouseleave(function(){
    $('#' + $(this).data('id')).css('display', 'none');
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

If you are not having the URL's point anywhere, I would recommend changing your structure slightly.

```
<ul class="menue">
  <li><a href="#">Startseite</a></li>
  <li><a href="#submenu-1">Menü1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#submenu-2">Menü2</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="subMenue initial" id="submenu-1"><a name="submenu-1"></a>Test-Menue1</div>
<div class="subMenue" id="submenu-2"><a name="submenu-2"></a>Test-Menue2</div>
```

It may be useful to add in a few more features, such as hiding your elements with Javascript in case someone tries to visit without Javascript enabled, then the links will point to the named anchors.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".subMenue").not(".initial").css("display", "none");//hide all but the initial div
  $(".menue li").hover(function(){
    $("#"+$(this).attr("href")).css("display", "block");
  },
  function(){
    $("#"+$(this).attr("href")).css("display", "none");
  });
```

});